# Redirecting stdout and stderr doesn't work with cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have the following cron task. Expected behavior is that every output (standard output and standard error output) of this task will be redirected to /dev/null. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Emails with errors are still sent.

```
7-57/10 * * * * wget -O - https://some.url.com/path/file.php?key=somerandomkey&folder=dwg >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: What exact Linux distribution/version are you running?

Comment: @Andrew Henle it's Rocky Linux 8.7

Comment: Put URL (with &) in quotes -`'wget -O - https://some.url.com/path/file.php?key=somerandomkey&folder=dwg'`.  Shell may interpret & as end of command to run in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to receive mails from `cron` set as first line (in `cron`) this:

```
MAILTO=""
```

And better create a script with the command and then do the redirect.